# Compiler error : Only Copy elision is wanted, but move constructor seems to be required (by compiler)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, rvo

Attempting to compile to this code give a compiler error with 'newer' compilers (im guessing: that support move constructors). Something along the lines of "attempting to call deleted function".

It turns out that compiling with gcc 8.1 and clang 6.0.0 when c++17 is enabled (thought to be due to the feature "guarenteed copy elision") is error free. However, it also became clear that with MSVC 19.14 (also with c++17 enabled) it fails, even though it should have that feature(came in 19.13). So is this just a bug with MSVC, is it allowed to do that, or is it another feature altogether ?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


class A : public std::stringstream {
public:
  A(std::string str) : str_(str) {
  }
  //A(A&&);

  ~A() {
     std::cout << str_;
  }
  std::string str_;
};


A make_A() {
  return A("hello");
}

int test(int num) {
    A test = make_A();
}
```

The 'A' class is a simply 'exploit' of copy-elision (or RVO - Return Value Optimization) and the fact that this doesn't invoke the custom destructor either.

Surprisingly, commenting in the declaration of A's move constructor, makes the code both compile AND link. So it could maybe look like the compiler first 'thinks' it needs the function - but later figures out the copy elision is possible.

This was the intended the behavior - that there should be no need for either calling.

Putting in the declaration without an implementation is no longer good practice.
I am also looking for a better solution.

Update: The code is used for a logger class that, when called, returns a temporary stringstream which when gets destroyed logs whatever is in the string buffer. The logger also has some internals of extra info of where to log, severity, etc.

Exact compile error with gcc 7.3:

```
<source>: In function 'A make_A()':

<source>:21:19: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'

   return A("hello");

                   ^

<source>:7:7: note: 'A::A(const A&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

 class A : public std::stringstream {

       ^

<source>:7:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits,
_Alloc>::basic_stringstream(const std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with
_CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'

In file included from <source>:4:0:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/sstream:734:7: note: declared here

       basic_stringstream(const basic_stringstream&) = delete;

       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:7:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ios<_CharT,
_Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'

 class A : public std::stringstream {

       ^

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/ios:44:0,

                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/ostream:38,

                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/iostream:39,

                 from <source>:3:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/basic_ios.h:475:7: note: declared here

       basic_ios(const basic_ios&) = delete;

       ^~~~~~~~~

<source>: In function 'int test(int)':

<source>:25:21: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'

     A test = make_A();

                     ^

Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Are you sure `B(const B&&)` is correct?  It should be `B(B&&)` and if it is it compiles just fine: https://godbolt.org/g/4PEFuP

Comment: `B(const B&&)` makes no sense, most of the time move steals the guts of the other objects, but you cant do that if its const.

Comment: "_Putting in the declaration without an implementation is no longer good practice._".   Have you considered using the [explicitly defaulted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicitly-defaulted-and-deleted-functions) move constructor?  That is... `A(A&&) = default;` - **note** I removed `const`

Comment: Maybe you can better explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I update the example. I had to change it into inheritance from stringstream as i could no longer get the simpel one to fail.

Comment: I also fixed the move constructor - but it didn't change anything.

Comment: `Something along the lines of "attempting to call deleted function".` — please add the exact error you're getting and remove mentions of `B` class which is now absent. Also, I'm unable to get your code compiling even if I comment out `A`'s move constructor (g++ 7.3.0), but that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @FrankBoyne I tried that now - it did solve it with the simpel example - but not when using std::stringstream (gives another compiler error related to deleted copy constructor of basic_ios if i recall correctly). I think it would be best to not have it all - since it is an error if this object is moved. We could make it moveable ofc. but that would require extra code to track, etc.

Comment: @Volt updated question with intended use

Comment: @yeputons ty, i updated the example and text.

Comment: @yeputons i also posted exact compiler error using gcc 7.3

Comment: You might consider using C++17, where RVO is in some situations mandatory instead of just allowed, removing the requirement for move-constructibility. Anyway, please add which Standard Version you compile for.

Comment: @Deduplicator using that gcc with -std=c++17 option actually solved the issue. Thanks for pointing my attention to that.

Comment: @Deduplicator turns out it didn't solve it anyway using MSVC 19.13 or 19.14. But a big thank you for pointing my attention to std compile flag (just assumed wrongly gcc and clang used that by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC Status of "Guarenteed copy elision" seems to buggy even with latest released version of MSVC (VS17 version 15.7.6).

See for example this ticked:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/217997/guaranteed-copy-elision-incomplete-in-1562.html

UPDATE: MS has fixed the issue with latest VS17 version 15.8.1